# Query a date range with DMZ DataMapper and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, orm, codeigniter-datamapper

I cannot find the solution in the docs for this simple problem.

I want to fetched a set of objects from the database in a specific date range.
I'm using DMZ Datamapper in the CodeIgniter environment.

```
    $items = new Entity();
    $items->where('date_created', 'date1 < x < date2'); 
    $items->get();
```

Maybe one needs to use the $items->where_in_func(...) method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is simple:

```
$items->where('date_created >', '2011-02-26 14:00:13'); 
$items->where('date_created <', '2011-02-26 16:00:13');
```